# Why does Ubuntu 16 forwarding not work?

Tags: networking, server, iptables

I try to implement the very simple Ubuntu forwarding from one IP to another. I don't care about security on that stage (it runs in sandbox now), I just need it to work.

I set `FORWARD` policy to `ACCEPT` and enabled forwarding in `sysctl.conf`. Next, I added TCP forwarding rules, so I have this:

```
# Filter settings
*filter
# Disallow incoming traffic
:INPUT DROP
# Allow forward traffic
:FORWARD ACCEPT
# Allow outgoing traffic
:OUTPUT ACCEPT

COMMIT


*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT
:OUTPUT ACCEPT

# Required to share Internet
-A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

-A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.0.107 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.100:80

COMMIT
```

Ubuntu computer IP is `192.168.0.107`. Another computer IP is `192.168.0.100`. So, I want to redirect Ubuntu 80 port to another computer address. Another computer runs HTTP server, so `http://192.168.0.100` on Ubuntu computer opens demo web page.

However, when I try to open `http://192.168.0.107`, it fails. When I run `curl` to get better error message, I get this:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.0.107 port 80: Connection refused
```

Does anyone have idea of this error reason?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the assumption that you are attempting to port forward on the same sub-net and via one network interface, which is unusual.

You have not dealt with the return path properly or used the correct pre and post routing tables. You have to map the returning packet so that it appears to the sender to have come from the original IP address that it sent the request to in the first place. Here is a tested example, but for my LAN:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# 1070028_firewall 2018.08.09 Ver:0.01
#       Basic port forwarding on one interface.
#       Note: this method is unusual.
#       Currently for this question:
#       https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070028/why-does-ubuntu-16-forwarding-not-work
#

# The location of the iptables program
#
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables

# Set some stuff
#
EXTIF="ens5"
UNIVERSE="0.0.0.0/0"
EXTIP="192.168.111.120"

#
echo Enabling forwarding...
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# Clearing any previous configuration
# and setting policies as per the question

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F OUTPUT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F FORWARD
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -X

# Clear the counters

iptables -Z
iptables -t nat -Z

# loopback interfaces are valid.

$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i lo -s $UNIVERSE -d $UNIVERSE -j ACCEPT

# forward path

$IPTABLES -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i $EXTIF --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.111.1:80

# with a default policy of ACCEPT, the following rule is not needed.
# shown here for completeness only.

# $IPTABLES -A FORWARD -p tcp -i $EXTIF -d 192.168.111.1 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

# return path

$IPTABLES -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXTIF -j SNAT --to-source $EXTIP
```

You should be able to use MASQUERADE instead of SNAT, but I didn't test it.